# Get error 401 authorization with Swagger but works properly in postman (dot net core)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger

I add swagger to my project and use authorization. It works properly with Postman but when want to use with Swagger get 401 Undocumented

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "APIs", Version = "v1" });
                
                c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                });

                c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                     {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Name = "Token",
                            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Token",
                            },
                        },
                        Array.Empty<string>()
                     }
                });
            });
           ...
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IUnitOfWork uow)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            //########################################## Swagger
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "APIs");
            });
            //##########################################

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
            ....
}
```

Comment: Do you see this Authorize button when swagger loads, and do you add ``Bearer {token}``?

Comment: @Aspram Yes, I see it and set it.

Comment: I get the same issue right now @SajjadZare did you figure it out?